# Cannot locate file when running docker container: /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 11: exec: "mypackage.sh": not found

Tags: python, bash, docker, aws-lambda

I am trying to deploy a docker container on an AWS lambda. I have followed several different guides (most recently this: https://blog.quiltdata.com/an-easier-way-to-build-lambda-deployment-packages-with-docker-instead-of-ec2-9050cd486ba8), but haven't had any luck yet.

Here is the code I tried:

```py
docker run --rm -v $(pwd)/create_table:/io -t bash package.sh
```

and the resulting error message:

```py
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 11: exec: package.sh: not found
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is package.sh in your directory?

Comment: Like @Chelmy88, if you don't have created package.sh in your directory it can't work. What is your filestructure?

Comment: Yes, package.sh was added to the directory in my Dockerfile

Comment: ADD package.sh /
ADD requirements.txt /
ADD py_extenstion_AWS.py /
ADD vectorizer_temp.sav /
ADD multiNB_temp_model.sav /

Comment: I verified that the file is there by opening a bash terminal inside of my docker container and calling `ls`